# quotient ring question

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $I = \{f(X) = \mathbb{C}[X] \mid f(0) = f(1) = f(−1) = 0\}$. Then $I$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{C}[X]$.

(iii) Show that all elements of $\mathbb{C}[X]/I$ can be written in the form $aX^2 + bX + c + I$, where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$.

(iv) For $a_2,a_1,a_0,b_2,b_1,b_0 \in C$, show that $a_2X^2 +a_1X +a_0 +I = b_2X^2 +b_1X +b_0 +I$ if and only if $a_2 = b_2,\,\,a_1 = b_1$ and $a_0 = b_0$.

I am completely stuck on both. I do have solutions of these but I really need someone to explain how to do these or guide me to do these types of questions. Correct me if I am wrong but is $\mathbb{C}[X]/I=\{a(X)+I \, : \, a(X)\in\mathbb{C}[X]\}$?

Comment: why am I getting negged?

Comment: I have written the question correctly but is there a typo on f(X)=C[X]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints.

Saying that a polynomial $f$ satisfies $f(a)=0$ is equivalent to saying it's divisible by $X-a$.

The polynomials is $I$ are all divisible by $X$, $X-1$ and $X+1$, hence by their product (why?). Conversely, a polynomial divisible by $X^3-X$ is in $I$ (why?).

Therefore $I$ is the ideal generated by $X^3-X$.

The rest is done by the division algorithm.

---

#### 1. Characterize $I$

Polynomials in $I$ are divisible by $X$, $X-1$ and $X+1$, because they have $0$, $1$ and $-1$ as roots. Since these three polynomials are irreducible and coprime, any polynomial in $I$ is divisible by $f(X)=X(X-1)(X+1)=X^3-X$.

Conversely, any polynomial divisible by $f(X)$ has $0$, $1$ and $-1$ as roots.

Therefore $I=(f(X))$ is the set of polynomials divisible by $f(X)$.

#### 2. A “canonical” form for the elements of the quotient ring

Let $a(X)\in\mathbb{C}[X]$. We want to write $a(X)+I$ in a better way. The division algorithm says we can find $q(X)$ and $r(X)$ such that
$$
a(X)=q(X)f(X)+r(X)
$$
and $r(X)=0$ or its degree is less than $3$. Since certainly $q(X)f(X)\in I$, we have that
$$
a(X)+I=r(X)+I
$$
because $a(X)-r(X)=q(X)f(X)\in I$.

Since the degree of $r(X)$ is less than $3$, we can write $r(X)=a_0+a_1X+a_2X^2$, so we have proved that any element in $\mathbb{C}[X]/I$ can be written in the form
$$
a_0+a_1X+a_2X^2+I
$$
for some $a_0,a_1,a_2\in\mathbb{C}$.

#### 3. The representation is unique

Suppose $a_0+a_1X+a_2X^2+I=b_0+b_1X+b_2X^2+I$. By definition we must have
$$
(a_0+a_1X+a_2X^2)-(b_0+b_1X+b_2X^2)=
(a_0-b_0)+(a_1-b_1)X+(a_2-b_2)X^2\in I
$$
which, by point 1, means $f(X)=X^3-X$ divides $(a_0-b_0)+(a_1-b_1)X+(a_2-b_2)X^2$. If this polynomial is non zero, it has degree less than $3$, so this can't happen; therefore the only possibility is that
$$
(a_0-b_0)+(a_1-b_1)X+(a_2-b_2)X^2=0
$$
(the zero polynomial), that is,
$$
a_0=b_0,\quad
a_1=b_1,\quad
a_2=b_2
$$

Comment: Your 'why' parts were actually shown in the previous parts. For iii, would this be OK? We know $$\mathbb{C}[X]/I = \{ a(X) + I | a(X) \in f(X) \}$$  
Let $a(X)\in f(X)$ so $a(0)=a(1)=a(-1)=0$ so $X(X-1)(X+1) | a(X)$ so $a(x)=q(X)(X^3-X)+r(X)$ with $r(X)=0$ or $\deg{r(X)}<3$ so we can write $r(X)=aX^2 + bX + c$. So let $a(X)+I\in \mathbb{C}/I$. So $a(X)+I=aX^2 + bX + c+I$. Is that even correct? I was unsure on whether $a(0)=a(\pm 1)=0$.

Comment: @snowman It could be worded better, but that's the idea.

Comment: But how do you know $a(0)=a(\pm 1)=0$? Because a(X) isn't in I, it is in f(X). how does that mean the factors are the same...?

Comment: Your $a(X)\in f(X)$ means nothing; the quotient ring is the set of objects of the form $a(X)+I$ where $a$ is *any* polynomial. So it need not satisfy $a(0)=a(1)=a(-1)=0$.

Comment: Is my equality of $\mathbb{C}[X]/I$ correct?

Comment: @snowman No. As I said, it means nothing.

Comment: You said a(X) means nothing, not the quotient ring... I dont get it at all. Please can you give a solution for iii.

Comment: just to make sure, is this what happened in point 2: $$a(X)+I=q(X)f(X)+r(X)+I=I+r(X)+I=0+I+r(X)+I=aX^2+bX+c+I$$

Comment: @snowman If you want to do it complicately, yes. Easier: $a(x)-r(x)\in I$.

Comment: I don't understand any other way lol. Also you said 'certainly $q(X)f(X)∈I$', but I don't see how because you just randomly named one of the polynomials f(X) right? So we could have written $q(X)t(X)$. But how do we know that this is in $I$? How do we know the factors of this?

Comment: Since $f(X)\in I$, any element of the form $q(X)f(X)\in I$ (by definition of ideal).

Comment: for iv what if I did this: ($\implies$) suppose that $a_2X^2 +a_1X +a_0 +I = b_2X^2 +b_1X +b_0 +I$ so $(a_2-b_2)X^2 +(a_1-b_1)X +(a_0-b_0) +I = 0+0X+0X^2 +I$, and by comparing coefficients we get $a_{2,1,0}=b_{2,1,0}$.          ($\leftarrow$) suppose that $a_{2,1,0}=b_{2,1,0}$. it is trivial to obtain $a_2X^2 +a_1X +a_0 +I = b_2X^2 +b_1X +b_0 +I$. Would this be OK?

Comment: on point 3, I don't understand how the second line comes into place. why is that in I? I thought that would be in C[X], Since for eg if we have ring R and a in R, then a+I={a+x : x in I}

Comment: @snowman This is very basic theory: $a+I=b+I$ if and only if $a-b\in I$.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me. I appreciate it sso much.